# How to evaluate this limit where $f(x)=x$ if $x\le 1$ and $1-x$ if $x>1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to evaluate $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1}f(x)$ where $f(x) =x$ if $x\le 1$ and $1-x$ if $x>1$. I graphed it and I am confused because it intersects at $(0.5, 0.5)$. I did my work and I said the limit as $x$ approaches $1$ from the left equals $x$ and the limit as $x$ approaches $1$ from the right equals $1-x$.

I am not sure if this is the correct answer.
Can someone guide me? The problem and work is posted below. Thank you. [image]

Comment: Option iii) is the correct one. Right hand and left hand limits are not equal.

Comment: What is "f(x)= if x<1"?

Comment: Please use $ signs around the mathematical formulae to format your question better.

Comment: Great I will do that next time. Thank you! Is there anywhere where I can learn math notation to format better?

Comment: here it [is](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/697953) @MichaelGuest

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi This helps so much thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x<1$, then $f(x)=x$; therefore, $\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=1$. And if $x>1$, then $f(x)=1-x$; therefore, $\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)=0$.

So, the limit $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: Great thank you very much! This helps a lot. Also, I understand why it isn't infinite because the functions cross each other and it's linear.